# Is this a good monoid action?

Tags: haskell, monoids

I think I might have stumbled across a general, albeit somewhat degenerate, [monoid action](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monoid-extras-0.5.1/docs/Data-Monoid-Action.html). Pseudo-Haskell:

```hs
instance (Monoid m, Monoid n) => Act m n where
    act mempty x = x  -- let's pretend that we can use `mempty` as a pattern
    act _ _ = mempty
```

`m`'s action on `n` is to set `n` to `mempty` unless `m` itself is empty.

Is this a law-abiding monoid action? Has it been invented before by someone other than me? If so, what is its name?

Comment: It seems like this might be something to do with [annihilators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilator_(ring_theory)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not look as a monoid action, at least in the general case. If it were, we should have the following properties:

```
-- law 1
act mempty            x = x
-- law 2
act (m1 <> m2) x = act m1 (act m2 x)
```

and, because of the way `act` was defined in the pseudo-instance:

```
-- property 1
act x y = mempty
   when x /= mempty
```

Take `m` and `n` to be `Sum Int`, which is a monoid.

We have

```
act (Sum 0) (Sum 1)
= { definition of mempty }
act mempty (Sum 1)
= { law 1 }
Sum 1
```

we also have

```
act (Sum 0) (Sum 1)
= { definition of <> on Sum }
act (Sum (-2) <> Sum 2) (Sum 1)
= { law 2 }
act (Sum (-2)) (act (Sum 2) (Sum 1))
= { property 1, given Sum (-2) /= mempty }
mempty
= { definition of mempty }
Sum 0
```

leading to two incompatible results.

On the other side, when `m` is a monoid where no (nontrivial) element has an inverse, e.g. `[a]`, then your `act` looks like a proper action.

Comment: This makes sense, thanks. Are there any restrictions I can apply to `m` so that I do have a monoid action? For example, if `m` is not a group? Or if `m`'s `mappend` is monotonic? (I might have said the same thing two ways there.)

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson You need more than "not a group". I guess you need "no element with an inverse, except mempty". In such case, it should be an action, I guess (?)

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. Any idea if this thing has a name?

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Not that I know. A free monoid should suffice, but you don't need the monoid to be completely free. E.g. on lists `x <> y = take 4 (x++y)` should be OK (?), even if it does not form a free monoid. Not sure if there's a standard name for this.